# how to edit x-axis label on histogram? on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-science

---

```
x = np.log(df_pitcher['adj_salary_filled'][df_pitcher['year'] == 2010])
y = np.log(df_pitcher['adj_salary_filled'][df_pitcher['year'] == 2015])
z = np.log(df_pitcher['adj_salary_filled'][df_pitcher['year'] == 2019])
_ = plt.hist(x, bins=20, alpha=0.5, label='2010 Season')
_ = plt.hist(y, bins=20, alpha=0.5, label='2015 Season')
_ = plt.hist(z, bins=20, alpha=0.5, label='2019 Season')
_ = plt.xlabel('Salaries')
_ = plt.ylabel('Frequency')
_ = plt.legend()
_ = plt.title('Distribution of Salaries for Pitchers')
_ = plt.show()
```

---

It's basically returning the log of my salaries, anyway to make it return the actual salary amount? I am taking the log because it'll help show the actual distribution.

[image: Salary Distribution]

Comment: What do you mean by "actual salary amount"?

Comment: its just a players salary for the season

Answer (score 0):

You can manually get/set the tick positions and the corresponding labels for the X axis using `plt.xticks`.

A easy way to fix your specific issue is to get the tick values and set their labels to be the square of each value:

```
tick_values, tick_labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(tick_values, [round(value**2, 3) for value in tick_values])
```